# WebStorm runs very very very slow and continually gives out of memory error

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, webstorm

I am using WebStorm on an 8Gb Mac to edit the source files for an ionic/cordova app. Lately, even though my app is very small WebStorm is working very very slowly (it literally takes seconds to respond to each key press!) and frequently throws out of memory errors.

I have assigned 2000Mb yet still it runs out of memory?

Why is it so slow? Why does it use so much memory? Is there some feature I can turn off to speed it up?

Comment: try disabling syntax highlighting.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Incompatible or misbehaving plugin, for example. There is no way to tell that without seeing your actual details. Suggestion: 1) Capture [Performance data](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems) 2) Submit all captured data (together with `idea.log` file) to [JB Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)

Comment: Have the same issue in EAP at the moment, did not have this before must be an ionic issue. I had the config on 750 megs, upped it to 1500 was full alsmost instantly, there must be a huge leak somewhere.

Comment: I think you are right about the memory leak. I think it is related to indexing and ionic build changing so many files.

Comment: Any news here? Having the same problem with my Ionic2 project right now...

Comment: in general Java behaves like a hog in apps

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that when we save a file, ionic re-deploys the app generating some files under www folder.

At the same time, Webstorm searchs for changes in our project and indexes new things. That makes it so slow and even sometimes enter an infinity loop.

The solution is to exclude "www" and "node_modules" folders from the project. That is:

- On left project panel right click on that folders and select: mark directory as -> excluded.

Comment: Thanks! saved my life and a mbpro down the window

Comment: Thanks! Excluding 'www' helps A LOT!

Comment: You can't mark node module directories as excluded in webstorm nowadays :-\

Comment: You probably dont want to exclude node_modules. Those directories contain important code if you want features like code completion , refactoring and other static analysis type stuff to work. Otherwise, frankly, just use Nano, since its those very features that gives the intellij ides their value proposition

Comment: I have `node_modules`folder marked as `excluded` for my `React-Native` project but it is still running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some supportings may help

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/tuning-webstorm.html